# problem with removing code from "miscellaneous scripts"

Tags: header, tags

After remove code script remained characters `});` although field is empty. Now, they can be seen on all pages.

Prompt please where magento saves scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you placed that under `Design -> HTML Head -> Scripts`

Its in table `core_config_data`

look for path `design/head/includes`